# Issue in changing the background of a scene in manim

Tags: manim

I can't seem to change the camera config in a scene in manim; i put the following code at the top of a scene:

```
CONFIG = {
    "camera_config":{"background_color": "#003399"}
}
```

but the background doesn't change; is there something else needed to change the background?

Comment: Share all the code and the result.

Answer (score 10):

Tried this from a GraphScene and it didn't work. What did work however was:

```
def construct(self):
    self.camera.background_color = WHITE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am supposed to answer here or if I should edit the question, anyway I got it, it was because I put the `CONFIG` line *after* def `construct(self)`